# Zeppelin Disconnect status error

Tags: angularjs, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm using Zeppelin 0.70. I can build zeppelin from git source. when i trying to start zeppelin on that port 8000 by using below command, it works good.

./zeppelin-daemon start

[image]

But It won't work after grunt serve command on the port 9000, but it started good and it shows web socket disconnected error.

```
[root@sandbox zeppelin-web]# ./grunt serve
Running "serve" task

Running "clean:server" (clean) task
Cleaning .tmp...OK

Running "wiredep:app" (wiredep) task

Running "wiredep:test" (wiredep) task

Running "concurrent:server" (concurrent) task

    Running "copy:styles" (copy) task
    Copied 16 files

    Done, without errors.


    Execution Time (2017-02-24 05:51:45 UTC)
    loading tasks  277ms  ▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▇ 91%
    copy:styles     28ms  ▇▇▇▇▇ 9%
    Total 305ms

Running "postcss:dist" (postcss) task
>> 16 processed stylesheets created.

Running "connect:livereload" (connect) task
Started connect web server on http://0.0.0.0:9000

Running "watch" task
Waiting...
```

[image]
I got log in console;

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:8080/api/security/ticket. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Where do i change 8080 to 8000.

Please tell me how do i resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think `grunt` was substituted with `npm` in 0.7 release, so could you try `npm run dev` command?

Update: There's ongoing issue under [ZEPPELIN-2154](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2154) related to it. In order to fix it in your case you could remove 3 lines in [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/4c60b27c3acbdd976bf8901ef52019380bb3c334/zeppelin-web/src/components/baseUrl/baseUrl.service.js#L27) of `if statement` and substitute it with `port = 8000;` in your source code. it could be temporary fix until patch is filed to make it configurable.

Comment: can you tell the hash of commit or whether it's 0.7.0 release source code

Comment: Please find my updated post. I got log in web console. It is trying to connect 8080, but zeppelin run 8000. How do i change this port no 8080 to 8000 on ./grunt serve command

Comment: That's good point, actually there's ongoing issue under [ZEPPELIN-2154](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN-2154). In order to fix it in your case you could remove 3 lines in [here](https://github.com/apache/zeppelin/blob/4c60b27c3acbdd976bf8901ef52019380bb3c334/zeppelin-web/src/components/baseUrl/baseUrl.service.js#L27) of `if statement` and substitute it with `port = 8000;` in your source code. it could be temporary fix until patch is filed to make it configurable.

Comment: I updated the answer. Also if run takes much more time than expected or if there's some anomaly in logs, please file an issue under https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ZEPPELIN or even can add as comment to the existing issue ZEPPELIN-2154.